# PHP round to 2 decimal issue

Tags: php

I've a function wich sum some payments.

```
function get_payment() {

   return 1439.60 + 1439.60 + 1439.60;

}

$a = get_payment();

var_export($a);

//I GET: $a = 4318.7999999999993;
```

Now i'm trying to round to 2 decimal without success

```
$b = round($a, 2);

var_export($b);

//I GET: $b = 4318.8000000000002;
```

I'd like to have 4318.80 **in FLOAT type to compare with others values**.

I don't want to use number_format (to display result)

Comment: i need float type return

Comment: related: https://floating-point-gui.de/

Answer (score 2):

`$b =  number_format((float)$a, 2, '.', '');`
This will make $b store as rounded $a

Comment: Ok tried and this works! but... can you tell me why ROUND() doesn't work?

Comment: Because `round` just increase previous digit if its next digit is greater than or equal `5`,

Comment: Because round looks just 1 decimal position away from the needed precision

Comment: The function round() returns float value. The float values ignore zeros from right end after the decimal point and left end before the decimal point. i.e. **04318.80000000000** is **4318.8** Check at https://3v4l.org/lF5V6

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is var_export, which for some reason, ignores the 'round'

```
var_export($a);
// 4318.79999999999927240423858165740966796875

$b = round($a, 2);
var_export($b);
// 4318.8000000000001818989403545856475830078125

var_dump($b);
// float(4318.8)

echo $b;
//4318.8
```

Answer (score 0):

as you do not want to use number_format , you can try with bcdiv

```
$b=bcdiv($a, 1, 2);
echo $b;
```